# DataAnnotations para verificação entre Hora Inicio e Hora Final

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, aplicação-web, mvc

Tenho dois campos do tipo [DataType(DataType.Time)], sendo eles Data Inicial e Data Final, e não posso deixar o usuário inserir a Data Final menor que a Data Inicial para fins de cálculo de horas trabalhadas.

Como faço para fazer a comparação entre dois campos de hora com DataAnnotations.

- podendo ser personalizada
- ou já existente dentro do MVC Asp.Net que Eu desconheço que já exista.

Desde já agradeço

Fico no aguardo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Lado Servidor

Você pode fazer uma comparação entre duas datas com um DataAnnotation personalizado, aqui vai um exemplo básico, mas que já da para ter uma idéia de como comparar as datas:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test
{
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
   public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
   {

      private string DateToCompareFieldName { get; set; }

      public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string dateToCompareFieldName)
      {
          DateToCompareFieldName = dateToCompareFieldName;
      }

       protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
       {
           DateTime laterDate = (DateTime)value;

           DateTime earlierDate = (DateTime)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(DateToCompareFieldName).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

           if (laterDate > earlierDate)
           {
               return ValidationResult.Success;
           }
           else
           {
               return new ValidationResult(string.Format("{0} precisa ser menor!", DateToCompareFieldName));
           }
       }
       
       //esse método retorna as validações que serão utilizadas no lado cliente
       public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
       {
           var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
           {
               ErrorMessage = string.Format("{0} precisa ser menor!", DateToCompareFieldName),
               ValidationType = "dategreaterthan"
           };

       clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("datetocomparefieldname", DateToCompareFieldName);

          return new[] { clientValidationRule };
      }

   }
}
```

Aí quando você for usar nas propriedades que você quer comparar:

```
public DateTime DataInicial { get; set; }

[DateGreaterThan("DataInicial")]
public DateTime DataFinal{ get; set; }
```

### Lado Cliente

Para a validação no lado cliente, primeiramente você deve, na sua classe de Data Annotation, implementar a interface *[IClientValidatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx)*, que é uma interface simples com apenas um método, *[GetClientValidationRules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx)*, o qual é utilizado para retornar as regras de validação no lado cliente da classe que a implementa.

você deve também criar um arquivo separado que conterá seu código de validação dos campos, por exemplo

*dateGreaterThanValidation.js*

e colocar o código para criar a validação (não se esqueça de referenciar esse arquivo na página em que você for fazer a validação):

```
(function ($) {
  $.validator.addMethod("dategreaterthan", function (value, element, params) {
      var otherProp = $('#' + params)
      return Date.parse(value) < Date.parse(otherProp.val());
  });
  
  $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("dategreaterthan", ["datetocomparefieldname"], function (options) {
    options.rules["dategreaterthan"] = "#" + options.params.datetocomparefieldname;
    options.messages["dategreaterthan"] = options.message;
});

} (jQuery));
```

Para informações mais detalhadas de exemplos de uso e cada uma das propriedades do IClientValidatable recomendo a leitura deste post [CUSTOM UNOBTRUSIVE JQUERY VALIDATION WITH DATA ANNOTATIONS IN MVC 3](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/), que apesar de estar com o MVC3, funciona também para as versões mais recentes do MVC.

Comment: Amigo @Gabriel Weber o código acima funciona perfeitamente, esta validando conforme minha necessidade.

Comment: Amigo @Gabriel Weber o código acima funciona perfeitamente, esta validando conforme minha necessidade.

Mas encontrei um probleminha, gostaria de ter mais uma ajuda sua.

A mensagem de erro da validação ValidationResult não acorre no mesmo tempo que a validação dos outros campos.

Explicando melhor, tenho 3 campos Data, Hora Inicial, Hora Final, se acontecer este caso.

Não preencho Data e preencho Data Inicial = 6:00 e Data Final = 5:00, somente o Required do campo Data aparece e neste caso a Data Inicial esta maior que a Data Final, então deveria aparecer a validação também.

Comment: @cyberlacs atualizei a minha resposta. O que estava acontecendo é que a classe original que eu respondi continha apenas a validação do lado servidor, por isso que só validava depois de que todas as validações no lado cliente ocorriam. Tenta ver a minha resposta e qualquer coisa dá uma lida no post que eu linkei no final da resposta.